# Set Width of Cells of Grid View?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

I have grid view and now i want to set specific width for each cell and i tried my best to set width of each cell but failed to do so...

here is code that i applied to my template field.

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblempid" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("EmployeeId") %>'></asp:Label>
<ControlStyle Height="10px" Width="20px" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

I am new in c# and ASP.Net so please guide me.

thanks in advance. :)

Comment: yes its working after a little modification :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set like this

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        <HeaderStyle Width="10%" />
        <RowStyle Width="10%" />
        <FooterStyle Width="10%" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="LastName" 
               ItemStyle-Width="10%"
                 />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

or

```
  int colWidth = 100;
  if (colWidth > 0)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
      GridView1.Columns[i].ItemStyle.Width = colWidth;
    }
  }
}
```